# The reason of using 「考えすぎたあまり」 instead of 「考えたあまり」

Tags: grammar, usage

In my textbook, the usage of 「〜あまり」 is described as follows:

> 〜すぎるので、〜すぎるために (so … that)

However one of the usage sentences is written as follows:

> 試験の問題は易しかったのに、*考えすぎたあまり*、間違えてしまった。

In this case, isn't the meaning of "Doing something so extremely that it results in an abnormal situation" repeated? So maybe it has to be written in this form:

> 試験の問題は易しかったのに、*考えたあまり*、間違えてしまった。

But my Japanese friend says that it is quite awkward. Why is it?

Comment: The preceding part before あまり needs to have some attribution that stands for excessiveness, if not すぎる. For example, 熟考のあまり would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> あまり【余り】
>   〘名詞〙
>   ➌《感情や動作を表す連体修飾語を受けて、全体で副詞句を作る》**それが原因となってある結果が引き起こされる**意を表す。～が過ぎたその結果として。「喜び［苦しさ］の**あまり**泣き出した」「勢いの**あまり**転がり落ちた」「成功を急ぐ**あまり**失敗した」

So I think you could rather think of this あまり as "as a result of~~".

> 考え*すぎた***あまり**、間違えてしまった。
>   **As a result of** *overthinking / reading too much into it*, I made a mistake.

「考えすぎる」 ＝ "to think too much" "to read too much into something"

> 「〜あまり」 is described as follows:
>   〜すぎるので、〜すぎるために (so … that)

I think that means you could rephrase the sentence as:

> 試験の問題は易しかったのに、考えすぎた**ので**、間違えてしまった。　
>   試験の問題は易しかったのに、考えすぎた**ために**、間違えてしまった。
>   "... because I thought too much / read too much into it, I made a mistake."

Examples:

「嬉しさの**あまり**泣き出した」≂「嬉しくて/嬉しすぎて泣き出した」
"started to cry *because of* joy"
「急ぐ**あまり**失敗した」≂「急いだために/急ぎすぎたために失敗した」
"failed *as a result of* hurrying"

But...

> 考えたあまり、間違えてしまった。

would mean "As a result of thinking, I made a mistake."

Comment: 明鏡は本当にこの辺りの説明がしっかりしてますね…

Answer (score 1):

> In my textbook, the usage of 「〜あまり」 is described as follows:
>   〜すぎるので、〜すぎるために (so … that)

In this interpretation you'll certainly get lost in a repeated maze.

The text should have been as:

> 〜すぎるあまり、〜すぎるあまりに (so … that)

Then, the following sentence will be interpreted without repeating.

> 試験の問題は易しかったのに、考えすぎたあまり、間違えてしまった。

*The question of the exam was easy, but I thought it so much that I made a mistake*.